# Is `for (auto&& e : a)` more effective than `for (auto& e : a)`?

Tags: c++, c++11

In terms of L2 cache misses for reading POD/short C struct collections is `for (auto&& e : a)` more effective than `for (auto& e : a)` and how is it in terms of code generation?

Comment: Use a profiler, check the output assembly. This kind of question depends on so many things that there's no way we can answer it for you.

Comment: You'll find information on "cache misses" much more easily if you spell the term correctly.

Comment: Either they're exactly equivalent, or `auto& e` won't compile.

Comment: @Barry that was my impression.  Isn't the && case immediately binding an rvalue reference to a named object, turning it into an lvalue?

Comment: @Columbo how is this not extremely specific?  The difference between those two is very well defined, and how it interacts with L2 cache misses and code generation is also really narrow.  In particular, one compiles in a strict subset of the other's cases, as Barry has mentioned.

Comment: Won't the actual code generation be compiler dependent?

Comment: @Almo Unlike most parts of C++, how automatic for loops work is defined in terms of equivalent code.  What type is deduced when you do `auto&&` or `auto&` is defined.  I may be wrong, but from what I can tell, the standard actually mandates they are *exactly equivalent*, insofar as the standard mandates any behavior at all, when they both compile.

Comment: [Here is a link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aade40522ca5cf6f) to a demonstration that the types deduced are identical for the various kinds of types that dereferencing an iterator can return.  The commented out cases do not compile (the rvalue reference and temporary bound to `auto&`), and the other cases generate the exact same type of variable.  @T.C. how, exactly, is this "too broad" of a question and "too long" of an answer?  I mean, I can see downvoting, or finding a dupe?

Comment: You convinced me. I cast the 5th reopen vote. :)

Comment: @Yakk Meh. The standard does not care about execution speed, so I see no reason why a hypothetical compiler couldn't pessimize one case.

Comment: @T.C. What would a conforming pessimization even look like?

Comment: @Barry Adding a million `nop`s whenever you use `auto &&`?

Comment: @T.C. HA! Ok, fair enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the standard:

> a range-based `for` statement is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> {
>     auto && __range = range-init;
>     for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
>                __end = end-expr;
>           __begin != __end;
>           ++__begin ) {
>         for-range-declaration = *__begin;
>         statement
>     }
> }
> ```

So the difference between `for (auto&& e : a)` and `for (auto& e : a)` reduces to the difference:

```
auto&& e1 = *__begin;
auto& e2 = *__begin;
```

If `*__begin` can bind to an lvalue reference, then the two are equivalent. `e1` and `e2` will deduce to the same, lvalue reference type on any conforming compiler and the generated code should be identical.

However, if such a binding is impossible (e.g. `a` is of type `vector<bool>`, the Best. Container. Ever.), then the `e2` type deduction will fail, and only the `e1` version will be valid.

So it's not a question of which one is more efficient. `auto& e` is valid only in a subset of cases that `auto&& e` is valid in (the latter being valid in all cases in which any range-for expression is valid). And if `auto& e` is valid, then it's exactly equivalent to `auto&& e`.

Comment: I object:  `vector<bool>` is clearly not a container.  It just looks like one!  (this is a joke about a flaw in the standard)